# Can i use TypeScript in place of JavaScript to make a Webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm actually a total newbie on programming, and i would like to learn how to make a proper webpage. Html, CSS and JavaScript is the basic trio for web programming according to what I've researched.

I've read TS is like a expanded version of JS which allows static type and many other functionalities but, **If i start learning TypeScript and use it instead of JavaScript in a webpage it works as if it were JS?**

Can I replace the JS place in a webpage with TS files?

**TypeScript is a priority**, since it's needed to an app I would like to code in a future. So, I would like to know whether start learning only TS or JS as well.

This is probably the most stupid question ever asked but I could not find an answer, Don't be so rough with me please.

Comment: Without a doubt, you need to learn JS first.

Comment: Well, typescript is not natively supported by browsers. I'm unsure what type of app you're going to make that it MUST be in typescript, but I'd definitely start with javascript first. After all, typescript is a superset of javascript. You should always learn how to cook meat before eating home-cooked meat :)

Comment: TS doesn't run neither in the browser, nor in nodejs. You have to compile it to JS first. But when comparing TS to modern JS, most of this compilation step is stripping the type signatures. Imo. it's not that big of a deal, wether you start with TS or JS; as a newbie you'll encounter the same problems. Stuff related to the context of variables, `this`, types (with or without type declaration) and the classic "trying to access property xyz of undefined". Oh, and everything related to async code; callbacks, promises, ...

Answer (score 5):

You can't use TypeScript directly in a web page the same way you'd be able to use JavaScript -- that is, you can't add a <script> tag and point directly at a TypeScript file as your src, nor can you enter TypeScript between script tags.

TypeScript has to be *compiled* into JavaScript for a web browser to understand it. At a minimum you need a TypeScript compiler, but generally you're not going to manually compile TypeScript code and then copy and paste the output into a web page, so beyond just the compiler you're typically going to rely on having a development environment set up using something like Angular CLI or webpack that automates the task of compiling your TypeScript and building it into your web page.

I wouldn't say you have to learn JavaScript first, but I'd recommend learning JavaScript side by side with TypeScript, learning the differences as you go along -- quite often even when you're trying to mostly use TypeScript you'll end up having to do a little pure JavaScript here and there as part of the "glue" needed to put a project together.